# Codeigniter: Get userdata from another table using session

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to print userdata from another table with session. The table with the session is "userlogin" while the table with the data is "userinfo"

Here's what I've done so far

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        if ( $this->session->userdata('logged_in') )
        {

            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('userinfo');
            $id = $session_data['id'];
            $this->load->model('Userdata_model');
            $result = $this->Userdata_model->get_user_data3($id);


            if($result==0)
            {
                echo 'No user Found';
            }
            else
            {
                $data['id']=$result;

                $this->load->view("userdata_view", $data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Model

```
public function get_user_data3($id)
    {
    if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {

        $userid = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
    } else {
        header("location: http://localhost/test");
    }

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id='$id'");

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            echo $row['fName'];
            echo $row['phone'];
        }

    }
```

View

```
 <?php foreach ( $query->result_array as $new_user )
            {
                ?>
                <h4>Your name: <?php echo $new_user['fName'] ?> </h4>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: I keep getting no result found each time

Comment: is there any error

Comment: I want to retrieve data from table "userinfo"

Comment: @geeth No error

Comment: do you get any value in `$id` ?

Comment: I still get no value in $id

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, Thanks, I'll adhere to this

Comment: Another thing to look into (beyond your session data) is that your model function get_user_data3 does not appear to be returning anything.

Comment: @cfnerd I add return $query but it still displays "no user found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change function  in controller :

```
public function index()
{
    if ( $this->session->userdata('logged_in') )
    {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('userinfo');
        $id = $session_data['id'];
        $this->load->model('Userdata_model');
        $data['result'] = $this->Userdata_model->get_user_data3($id);

        $this->load->view("userdata_view", $data);

    }
}
```

change model function like:

```
public function get_user_data3($id)
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id='$id'");

    return $query;

}
```

and view :

```
<?php if($result->num_rows() == 0){
         echo 'No user found';
      }
      else {
        foreach ( $result->result_array() as $new_user ){ ?>
           <h4>Your name: <?php echo $new_user['fName'] ?> </h4>
<?php   } 
      }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, it still displays no user found

Comment: check your `$session_data`

Comment: `$id = $this->session->userdata('userinfo');`

Comment: Sorry, "no user found"

Comment: @cfnerd How can i turn on the profiler? I include the session data to the view page but still displays "no user found"

Comment: @cfnerd after turning on the profiler, i couldn't see any data stored in the session

Comment: @cfnerd I just included the session variables

Comment: @cfnerd, I could see session variables, but still getting "no user found"

Comment: @N. francis - it appears [you attempted to edit the answer by geeth](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17735018). Instead, please [edit **your** post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46931259/edit)

Comment: Hi @SamOnela, I didn't edit his post, I edited mine, check again. Can you advice how to solve this? thanks

Comment: @N. francis don't mention :)

Comment: Hi @geeth, I'm encountering another issue, Please could you find time to review [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951288/codeigniter-update-table-from-another-table-with-session) Thanks